# How can I create a settings button in Android's app info page?

Tags: android, android-settings

Nova Launcher opens their settings with the cogwheel in the upper right. How is this done? How would I place my app's settings activity there?

[image: Nova settings button in System Settings -> Apps -> Nova Launcher]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Android 7.0 and higher, you can use this `<intent-filter>` on your settings activity:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The Settings app should pick that up and make it available to the user via that gear icon.