# Android show settings activity in app info screen

Tags: android

What do I have to specify to make the Settings app show this on my app (must be something in the manifest I believe):

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105494/how-can-i-create-a-settings-button-in-androids-app-info-page

Comment: You may find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366649/any-way-to-link-to-the-android-notification-settings-for-my-app

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question, You want to start settings activity form the icon click.

for click event,  start settings activity

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);`

Override the OnACtivityResult Method and you can get the Settings action there,

For type of settings refer the bellow documentation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Cheers!! Hope this will help.

Comment: Nope. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I want my app to have that Gear icon in the Notifications section in the stock Settings app. The screenshot is attached.